# Alt drag does not work properly

Tags: front-end, bugs, keyboard

When a graphics is displayed, right clicking will bring up the *Get Coordinates* tool. To select a rectangular region, you can do it manually by selecting the two corners and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will copy these two points for you to use. This works fine, but you are supposed to be able to hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd>  while dragging a rectangle. Then you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the corners as before. I tried three different keyboards and three different mice, but this does not work on my new version of Mathematica 10 on Windows 8. The other functionality of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> works fine. This might be an issue with Windows 8. Thanks in advance for any advice.
(Of course I tried <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> and every other combination of keys.)

Comment: I've tried this on my Win8 PC. Rectangle selection (Alt drag) works in version 8 only, and not in 9 or 10. Path selection (simple drag) works in 8 and 9 but not in 10. Looks like a bug indeed. Could you report this to support@wolfram.com?

Comment: For copying coordinates under Windows the [documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/GetCoordinates.html) keyboard combination is Ctrl+C. It works but rectangle selection (Alt+drag) does not work in version 10.1 under Win7 while works in version 8.0.4.